# VHDL Case/When: multiple cases, single clause

Tags: case, vhdl

Inside a process I have something like this:

```
CASE res IS
  WHEN "00" => Y <= A;
  WHEN "01" => Y <= A;
  WHEN "10" => Y <= B;
  WHEN "11" => Y <= C;
  WHEN OTHERS => Y <= 'X';
END CASE;
```

Note that case `"00"` and `"01"` get the same value. Is there a correct syntax for something like

`WHEN "00", "01"  =>` ?

*Extra note: There's far more to this than Y being changed, I just used that for simplicity. So the case/when is necessary.*

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can separate multiple choices with the "pipe" or bar symbol.  The proper syntax for your example is:

```
CASE res IS
  WHEN "00" | "01" => Y <= A;
  WHEN "10" => Y <= B;
  WHEN "11" => Y <= C;
  WHEN OTHERS => Y <= 'X';
END CASE;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also give a range of choices for a case:

```
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

CASE TO_INTEGER(res) IS
  WHEN 0 to 1 => Y <= A;
  WHEN 2 => Y <= B;
  WHEN 3 => Y <= C;
  WHEN OTHERS => Y <= 'X';
END CASE;
```